# How to reshape S3 object to make it comparable?

Tags: unit-testing, r

I use test_that for unit testing and I'm trying to compare two objects.  In some cases, regardless of the contents, it seems that the two objects are never identical (`expect_identical`), but can be equal (`expect_equal`) if they are of the same class.  I'm sure it has to do with how the class is constructed (I'm using R.oo)

So...is it possible to reshape/flatten/restructure an object (possibly into a list?) so that the raw data is extracted, thus making two objects comparable?  I realize that this might be an impossible task.  I don't know enough about environments in R to say for sure.

**Edit**
Here's an example:

```
library(R.oo)
library(testthat)

setConstructorS3( "MyClass" , function( )
{
    extend( Object() , "MyClass" ,
            .param1 = rnorm(10)
          )
} )

test1 = MyClass()
test2 = MyClass()
expect_identical(test1, test2) # error: Objects equal but not identical
expect_equal( test1, test2) # no error reported
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with test_that, but the issue is probably caused by precision (is there a tolerance-type argument to `expect_identical`?) or different attributes (is there an `expect_equal_attributes`?).

Comment: Can you post an example of two such objects?

Comment: Joshua - There are three relevant expectation checkers: expect_identical, expect_equals, expect_equivalent.  identical has to be identical.  equals allows numerical tolerance, but that's really not relevant here when objects have completely different values and still pass "equals".  equivalent is a relaxed version of equals (ignores attributes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of interactive exploration with `str` lead me to this:

```
as.list.Object <- function(x, ...) {
  vars <- as.list(attr(x, ".env"), all = TRUE)

  vars[substr(names(vars), 1, 3) != "..."]  
}

all.equal.Object <- function(target, current, ...) {
  all.equal(as.list(target), as.list(current), ...)
}

expect_equal(test1, test2)
# Error: test1 not equal to test2
# Component 1: Mean relative difference: 1.056427
```

Comment: hadley - brilliant, not just for the solution but also for the new learnings.  I assume all.equal is recursive in the sense that if I compare two lists that contain Object, the comparison will work fine?  Also the case where an Object contains another Object?

Comment: Hmmm. To be recursive I think you'd need another check. Exercise left to reader ;)

Comment: Actually, it seems to work fine recursively.  I tested two cases: 1. comparing ObjectA/ObjectB where A/B contains Object C/D.  2. placing Object A/B in their own lists and comparing those lists.